# Create new sequence from existing

Tags: clojure

i'm trying to learn some clojure, and now i'm stuck whith sequence. 
I whant to create a new sequence from existing, but newone must contain only top level elements or sum of all nested. For example, from '(1 2 (3 4)) there must be '(1 2 7). I think i'm on the right way to nailed it, but i've got an error:

```
user=> (make-new '(1 2 (3 4)))
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long 
   clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

Here's my code:

```
(defn sum
[list]
(reduce + (into-array (flatten list))))

(defn make-head
 [item]
 (if (seq? (first item))
  (sum (first item))
  item
 ))

(defn make-new
 [list]
 (cons(make-head (first list)) (seq (make-new (rest list)))))
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `first` from `make-head`, as you're already calling `first` from `make-new`:

```
(defn make-head [item]
  (if (seq? item)
    (sum item)
    item))
```

Also, just use `(map make-head list)` in `make-new`. There's no need to implement `map` yourself:

```
(defn make-new [list]
  (map make-head list))
```

Finally, `+` already reduces (it's variadic), so you can just implement `sum` like this:

```
(defn sum [list]
  (apply + (flatten list))
```

---

A more concise approach, exploiting the fact that `(flatten [42])` results in `(42)`:

```
(defn make-new [xs]
  (map #(apply + (flatten [%])) xs))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `for`:

```
(for [i '(1 2 (3 4))]
  (if (seq? i)
    (reduce + i)
    i))
```